# Benefits Of VPS-Servers

Tags: vps

I want know About benefits of Vps Servers And How Can I Use This Server?

Can I Implement Vpn-server,Mail-server or other think with this?

Please Help me

Comment: It's best if the Virtual Private Server Server has gigabit NIC cards, sufficient RAM memory and a RAID array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A VPS is basically a step above normal cheap webhosting and a step below getting your own dedicated (or colocated) server.

Where as when you get cheap webhosting, you typically can only do very limited things - e.g. host a site and a few email boxes. When you get a VPS or dedicated server, you basically have full control over the (virtual) machine and can do what you want - this includes installing your own mail and web servers.

You can (as you asked) install VPN servers, there is nothing technically stopping you, however, usually many VPS hosts have no VPN endpoints in their terms and conditions (to try and stop illegal usage).

To sum up, benefits - higher flexibility than normal hosting, lower cost than dedicated with pretty much the same benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Anything (well almost) you can do with a real server you can do with a VPS. It's just a server that happens to be virtualized (see VMWare, VirtualBox, VirtualPC).

The advantage of a virtual server is that it (in most cases depending on provider) easy and fast to upgrade/downgrade storage/RAM/computing power. It's just for the provider to change a setting in their virtualization software.

A disadvantage is that you can never be 100% sure of what capacity you will get at all times as several VPS share hardware.

Comment: @jason don't know where you order your VPS' from but I've always gotten at **least** 2 static IPs, never shared.

Comment: @jason404 I agree with John T. I've *never* seen a VPS that uses a shared IP. Perhaps you were mistaking VPS systems with share webhosts?

Comment: @jason404 - rubbish. VPS are not shared webhosting. THere is no way multiple servers share one IP address and are real servers. Many protocols are not shareable. YOu mix up web hosting (virtual web host) and VPS.

Comment: Oh okay, I was wrong about this.

Answer (score 1):

As Wil stated, it's a step up from shared hosting. When your website or company is starting to blossom, and a dedicated server isn't quite appropriate yet budget-wise, a VPS is a great step up. These days you can get a VPS plan on a multicore box with 512M ram for around $6, so much more flexibility without a lot of extra cost!

Having a VPS is just like having your own dedicated server, except you will share resources with others. The advantage of this is that if another user isn't using their allotted CPU/Memory, you can tap into their resources until they need it. This is usually referred to as "burstable" resources. Another **huge** advantage of having your own VPS is unrestricted full root access. 99% of the time VPS hosts will give you full root access, compared to shared hosting where you rarely even get basic shell access on a user account. This is a huge step up as you can install pretty much anything you'd like, whether it be a mail server, web server, DNS server, or just your own little playground learning box. Need a Perl module installed? Sure. No fighting your shared host and e-mailing them back and forth when you need something small like that.

The other great part about owning a VPS is you can break anything you want, and a full OS reinstall is 1 click away (and almost instantaneous with virtual templates in use)!

And now, for the fine print: Some hosts' TOS will come back and bite you. Ensure you read each one fully before diving in. A lot will advertise things like an "unlimited 10mbps connection" and then later on state that if you use too much bandwidth they will drop your line to 2mbps for example. Also make sure you ask if a certain application is acceptable on the servers before buying. A lot of hosts don't appreciate hosting IRC servers or BNC/eggdrops.